# Unable to comment on a migrated question?

Tags: support, comments, migration

My question got migrated from stackoverflow to serverfault.

[Disable ProxyPass rules within a virtual host on apache 2](https://serverfault.com/questions/82015/disable-proxypass-rules-within-a-virtual-host-on-apache-2)

I got one answer on that till now, but I'm unable to comment on that. Is this because this question was migrated and **serverfault** doesn't recognize me as the author of the question (probably due to openid being used as login??). I used same openid provider/user in both sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Associate your accounts.

From your profile select the accounts tab on the far right.

Comment: I thought I did this. Apparently I did not.. ;)

Comment: It's the Google ID that gives you problems.